# Answers that are accepted but contain wrong information

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

How do we handle the case where an accepted answer clearly contains wrong information?

Comment: Perhaps you could offer some examples?

Comment: I thought that I had one, but really I just failed to read the whole thing. I doubt this is really a concern since all of the questions are supposed to be subjective and I realized that this is what the flag and down vote function are for. So, I answered my own question.

Comment: Related: [Answers that irritate me.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/779/answers-that-irritate-me), [What happens when an accepted answer is wrong but the OP is gone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/what-happens-when-an-accepted-answer-is-wrong-but-the-op-is-gone), [Why do incorrect answers keep getting “accepted”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7572/why-do-incorrect-answers-keep-getting-accepted)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best you can do is leave a comment on the answer and/or the post itself. You can also downvote the answer.